# Missing nested button in Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, solution-explorer

As seen in the image, the nested button is what is missing from my solution explorer. When I try creating a asp.net core web app model view controller mvc project I am not seeing the appropriate views and things are missing from the drop down menu.

What it should look like:

[image: Nested button on solution explorer]

Also this is what I should see and I'm not:

[image: Image showing the nested button is not present]

Answer (score 0):

Since you said ASP.NET MVC and not *ASP.NET Core*, this icon will not display according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022):

> In Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2 and earlier, this feature was only supported for ASP.NET Core projects. In version 17.3 and later the projects targetting .NET support file nesting.

Your project(s) need to be targeting ASP.NET Core (or with more recent versions of Visual Studio, *.NET* as its called now).

Comment: Timothy G. , it is asp.net core web app model view controller (mvc)

Comment: What version Visual Studio? @karina

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022

Comment: @Karina I meant specific version (i.e. 17.0 or 17.1, etc).  But I just noticed something, You have an arrow seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajl0w.png click on it, it should show more options.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.5.3

Comment: Not seeing that @Timothy

Comment: Those two uploads is what should be there. I am not seeing those things .. no arrows buddy

Comment: @Karina post what your actual solution explorer looks like with your project files if you can.

Comment: send me an email @ sexy_angel_619@hotmail.com. I'll send the images